# How to check if a specific JSON value exists in an API GET Request in Python?

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

I am not sure if it's possible to check if a value of a specific key exists in an API GET Request Response.
The below code does not work.

```
 req = requests.get('MYAPI')
 response = req.json()
 if 'Tom' in res:
   print('Welcome')
```

Comment: Please edit your question and [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) format the code so it's easier to read ^

Comment: try to check what's inside the `res` using `print(res)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.json` actually returns a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) of items. To reveal the contents of a dictionary, you can use `print` function like below:

```
my_dictionary = {'first_name': 'joe', 'last_name': 'biden', 'age': 14}
print(my_dictionary)  # {'first_name': 'joe', 'last_name': 'biden', 'age': 14}
```

So whenever you want to find what is inside a dictionary, use `print`.

Additionally, you could also use the fact that a dictionary is also an iterable object. This basically means, that you can iterate through the dictionary item by item. Here's a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) that shows you how. Combine that with the fact that you want to find out whether at least one of those items is `"Tom"`. Can you figure it out now?